# how to write a true default method to avoid code duplication

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface

I want to write two classes implement interface with default method with parameter - function name and use it in both classes, but don know how to put method name as a parameter. It necessary to avoid duplication.

```
interface C {
        default public StatusEntry getServiceStatus(){????}
}

class A implements C { 

    private StatucBType getSatusA(){...} 

    @Override
    public StatusEntry getServiceStatus() throws Exception {
        StatusEntry result = new StatusEntry();
        ServiceStatus status;
        try {
            status = **getSatusA()**/*need make as a parametr*/.getStatus();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        result.Status(status);
        return result;
    }
}

class B implements C {    
    private StatucBType getSatusB(){...}

    @Override
    public StatusEntry getServiceStatus() throws Exception {
        StatusEntry result = new StatusEntry();
        ServiceStatus status;
        try {
            status = **getSatusB()**/*need make as a parametr*/.getStatus();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        result.Status(status);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: What should be the `parameter`?

Comment: What is the default method, there I can see public and privet methods

Comment: "getSatusA()" or "getSatusB()"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a parameter to the method `getServiceStatus` in your interface, the concrete implementations must also add this parameter, and - more important - the callers of that method must know what argument to provide.

So first of all, don't add a parameter to that interface (at least, it's not necessary in this little scenario)!

For avoiding code duplication, you can add an intermediate abstract class hosting the code:

```
abstract class Z {

    final StatusEntry getServiceStatus(Supplier<StatucBType> statusProvider) throws Exception {
        StatusEntry result = new StatusEntry();
        ServiceStatus status;
        try {
            status = statusProvider.get().getStatus();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        result.Status(status);
        return result;
    }

}
```

Then use it as following:

```
class A implements C extends Z { 

    private StatucBType getSatusA() {...} 

    @Override
    public StatusEntry getServiceStatus() throws Exception {
        return getServiceStatus(this::getStatusA);
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, but if I have two different classes returned by getSatusA -> StatusAType  and getSatusB -> StatusBType. StatusAType and StatusBType have not common interfaces and abstract classes can I use Supplier<Object> ?

Comment: ... or a common supertype.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for the [template method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Your interface should have just a `getStatus` method,

```
StatucBType getStatus();
```

and the `getServiceStatus` method will be `default` and implemented like this:

```
default StatusEntry getServiceStatus() throws Exception {
    StatusEntry result = new StatusEntry();
    ServiceStatus status;
    try {
        status = getStatus().getStatus();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    result.Status(status);
    return result;
}
```

Now you need to implement `getStatus` in `A` and `B`:

```
// in A
public StatucBType getStatus { /*put the implementation of getStatusA here*/}
// in B
public StatucBType getStatus { /*put the implementation of getStatusB here*/}
```